# Реализация односвязного списка

Tags: python, ооп

Нашёл интересную реализацию односвязного списка. В отличии от моей через цикл, мне она показалось интересной. Но я не до конца понимаю как она работает

```
class ListObject:
    next_obj = None

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data[0]
        if len(data[1:])!=0:
            self.link(ListObject(data[1:]))

    def link(self, obj):
        self.next_obj = obj


sub_list = ['tree',
            '[A-Z]',
            'filter: FX - 2000',
            'E:equal, D:dodge',
            '555',
            'del',
            'Singleton']

linked_list = ListObject(sub_list)
```

В инициализаторе вызываем метод link() тем самым устанавливаем ссылку на следующий
элемент в data. Дальше я не понимаю как работает эта хитрая рекурсия. Почему метод вызывается снова и снова пока len(data) не станет == 0.
В итоге приходим к [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел в дебагере, выглядит как разрез списка до 2 элементов и на обратном ходу установка нужных next_object. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я совсем зелёный в питоне и попрошу без 'Учиться надо было', 'ты шо тупйhэто ж легкотня читай луса'

Comment: потому что смотрите Вы не туда, нужно смотреть на конструктор, `if len(data[1:])!=0:             self.link(ListObject(data[1:]))`. Вот Вы вроде бы правильно описываете работу кода, и тут бац - говорите что не понимаете как он работает, для меня это тоже загадка)

Comment: выглядит так что в data[1:]  link() отщипывает по 1 элементу и в обратном порядке по 1 элементу начинает присваивать next_obj. Как называется такой трюк? Я через цикл из вне такое бы сделал, а тут прям в инициализаторе в 1 условие, просто кинь данные.
Очень похоже на рекурсию, но ведь это вызов функции внутри себя...

Comment: тут Вы правильно мыслите, это рекурсия, а в качестве функции выступает конструктор объекта `ListObject`, а вот насколько она оправдана зависит от объема данных, все таки стек не резиновый, цикл надежнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не учитывал то, что в self.link(ListObject(data[1:])) так-то передается объект класса, а значит **init** будет вызываться рекурсивно. Теперь реализация не выглядит такой классной, конструктор перегружен